# Is there a configuration option that lets me limit the percent of a hard drive that Cassandra uses?

Tags: disk-space, cassandra

I'm doing some testing with a small hard disk and I'd like to basically stop Cassandra in its tracks if a write or compaction or any other service brings that usage of the disk above a certain percentage. Is there any way to do that? How could I approach this problem?

Thank you! :)

Answer (score -1):

I dis not saw such a option by Cassandra configuration, but you can use OS quota to limit disk usage.

Or more sophisticated is to write own small script to stop Cassandra, when Cassandra disk usage is too high. It will not be very long.